# Android soft input mode, deactivation on navbar

Tags: java, android

The soft input keyboard make my navbar go above the keyboard. The text edit behave in a correct way but I want to deactivate the soft input keyboard for the navbar. I can deactivate the soft input but I need it for the edit text. Is it possible to deactivate it in the xml layout or activate it for some parts ?

[normal navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xN3Cw.png)

[soft input navbar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1vooM.png)

The code

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:background="@color/PaleCerulean"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegisterPatientTitle"
        style="@style/title"
        android:text="Sign up patient"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvRegisterPatientSubtitle"
        style="@style/subtitlePatient"
        android:text="Enter your personnal informations"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvRegisterPatientTitle" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/tvRegisterPatientSubtitle"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/navbar">
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRegisterPatientLastName"
                android:text="Last name"
                style="@style/label" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisterPatientLastName"
                style="@style/editText"
                />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRegisterPatientFirstName"
                style="@style/label"
                android:text="First name" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisterPatientFirstName"
                style="@style/editText" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRegisterPatientEmail"
                style="@style/label"
                android:text="Email" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisterPatientEmail"
                style="@style/editText" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRegisterPatientPassword"
                style="@style/label"
                android:text="Password" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisterPatientPassword"
                style="@style/editText"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
            <ProgressBar
                android:id="@+id/pbRegisterPatient"
                style="?android:progressBarStyleHorizontal"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:max="4"
                app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
                tools:progress="1"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"/>
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvRegisterPatientPasswordConfirm"
                style="@style/label"
                android:text="Password Confirmation" />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/etRegisterPatientPasswordConfirm"
                style="@style/editText"
                android:inputType="textPassword"/>
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/btnRegisterPatientValidate"
                style="@style/buttonPatient"
                android:text="validate"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <include
        layout="@layout/navbar"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: In the first place, the soft keyboard shouldn't appear when you press it, can you post your navbar layout? Also if confusing what you want to achieve. Try to explain more clear.

Answer (score 0):

The current behavior is the same with **adjustResize** which means :

> Always resize the window: the content area of the window is reduced to
> make room for the soft input area.

When keyboard is showing, the window behind it is actually resized. You see navbar is moved above keyboard because it's pinned to the bottom of its parent. Bottom of parent is now top of the keyboard. The first two TextViews are visible because there still is enough room for them and other views can be accessed through scrolling because there is enough room for their ScrollView too.

Anyway, for this layout if you don't want navbar above keyboard, just set windowSoftInputMode to **adjustNothing** or **adjustPan (if you want user can always see what they're typing)**.

Set it for a specific style:

```
<item name="android:windowSoftInputMode">adjustNothing</item>
```

Or an activity :

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustNothing">
```